# meta box not display data input in the textarea

Tags: php, metabox

I've had multiple errors with this metabox, first I thought Id fixed a undefined index error with the code below but now that doesn't appear my metabox doesn't save any data.

code before the error:

```
if ( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
        return $post_id;
```

I tried adding the following to fix the undefined index error on line 108

```
 if ( !isset( $POST['excerpt_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['excerpt_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
        return $post_id;
```

after adding this now any data I put in the metabox doesn't save.

any help would be appreciated

code for excerpt meta box

```
 <?php
// Add the Meta Box  
function vs_add_excerpt_meta_box() {  
    add_meta_box(  
        'excerpt_meta_box', // $id  
        'Excerpt Meta Box', // $title   
        'vs_show_excerpt_meta_box', // $callback  
        'post', // $page  
        'normal', // $context  
        'high'); // $priority  
}  
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'vs_add_excerpt_meta_box');  

// Field Array  
$prefix = 'custom_';  
$excerpt_meta_fields = array(  
    array(
        'label' => 'Custom post teaser',
        'desc'  => 'Replace the default excerpt with the text of your choice',  
        'id'    => $prefix.'excerpt',  
        'type'  => 'textarea' 
        )
);  

// The Callback  
function vs_show_excerpt_meta_box() {  
global $excerpt_meta_fields, $post;  
// Use nonce for verification  
echo '<input type="hidden" name="excerpt_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';  

    // Begin the field table and loop  
    echo '<table class="form-table">';  
    foreach ($excerpt_meta_fields as $field) {  
        // get value of this field if it exists for this post  
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);  
        // begin a table row with  
        echo '<tr> 
                <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th> 
                <td>';  
                switch($field['type']) {  
                    // case items will go here   
            // textarea  
            case 'textarea':  
                echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                    <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
            break; 

                } //end switch  
        echo '</td></tr>';  
    } // end foreach  
    echo '</table>'; // end table  
}  

// Save the Data  
function vs_save_excerpt_meta($post_id) {  
    global $excerpt_meta_fields;  

    // verify nonce  
    if ( !isset( $_POST['excerpt_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['excerpt_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
        return $post_id;  
    // check autosave  
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
        return $post_id;  
    // check permissions  
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
            return $post_id;  
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
            return $post_id;  
    }  

    // loop through fields and save the data  
    foreach ($excerpt_meta_fields as $field) {  
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
        if ($new && $new != $old) {  
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
        }  
    } // end foreach  
}  
add_action('save_post', 'vs_save_custom_meta');    
?>
```

Comment: It is `$_POST`, not `$POST`

Comment: Changed that s_ha_dum and it still doesn't display anything in the field After I update it.

Comment: I was hoping it was a simple typo :)

Comment: So was I would of been very nice for us all :) I'm sure its a typo of some sort though sure of it.

Comment: You seem to be having a lot of trouble with metaboxes. Have you given any thought to using something like http://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/ or farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/ or even http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/ to handle the more complicated aspects for you?

Comment: I prefer to teach myself and make things work the long way instead of taking shortcuts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you do have a typo :

```
add_action('save_post', 'vs_save_custom_meta');
```

should be :

```
add_action('save_post', 'vs_save_excerpt_meta');
```

So you meta box does not have a valid callback. Change this and it will work ^^

Comment: You are great jma! thanks for that I was looking so hard at my code I didn't see the simpleness of this fault :O